# ls, rm, or perform other operations on a directory who's name begins with '$'

Tags: special-characters

I accidentally created a directory who's name begins with the "$" character, and now I can't figure out how to `ls` its contents or `rm -r` it altogether.

I've tried quoting the name like this `ls "$[dir-name]"` as well as escaping the special character like `ls \$[dir-name]`, neither of which worked.

Any tips? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using double quotes fails since the shell will still try to expand the variable, but escaping it *should* work unless there are *other* characters that may cause an issue as well. Try single quotes.

```
ls '$foo'
```

Answer (score 0):

Supposing your file is named $file, you can also `rm *file`. In zsh, you could also `rm ?file`.

Comment: think twice before executing `rm *file` because that will delete all files with filenames ending in "file"